# change the name of of a file via powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I created a .ps1 script which run remotely a .exe file on multiple servers. That .exe file create an output.xml. Now I want to change that name of it, which is the same for each server with a random name or if it is possible with the name of the server where that .exe is running. Below you can see my code:

```
foreach ($computers in ($computers =  Get-Content 'C:\test\comp.txt'))
 {
$server ={& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myexe.exe' --outputfile='C:\test.xml'}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $server -ComputerName $computers  
}
```

Myexe.exe file run on each computer  defined in $computers variable.
Exist the possibility to change the name of test.xml o each server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`$env:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.1) variables, follow the link for more information. In this case you can use `$env:COMPUTERNAME` to get the hostname of each server:

```
foreach ($computer in (Get-Content 'C:\test\comp.txt'))
{
    # Note you can Append the Date too to your outfile
    # Example: "C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME - $([datetime]::Now.ToString('MM.dd.yy HH.mm')).xml"
    # Would return a filename "serverName1 - 06.17.21 13.35"
    $server ={& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myexe.exe' --outputfile="C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.xml"}
    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $server -ComputerName $computer
}
```

On the other hand, you don't really need a `foreach` loop to go through all your computers. `Invoke-Command -ComputerName` argument accepts an array of computers:

```
$computers =  Get-Content 'C:\test\comp.txt'
# Assuming $computers holds each hostname in a new line like
# computername1
# computername2
# ...
# ...

# This should work just fine
$server ={& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\myexe.exe' --outputfile="C:\$env:COMPUTERNAME.xml"}
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $server -ComputerName $computers
```

Comment: hello, I tested the second example and the code works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @superwomen no problem! happy to help :)